# names_to_bands.setdefault(name,[]).append('Wings')

Tags: python

функция в цикле возвращает в цикле список с именем и названием группы
Вопрос почему при повторном прогоне она добаляет имя группы к уже существующему имени?

```
band1_names = ['John', 'George', 'Paul', 'Ringo']
band2_names = ['Paul']
names_to_bands = {}
for name in band1_names:
    names_to_bands.setdefault(name,['Beatles'])
for name in band2_names:
    names_to_bands.setdefault(name,[]).append('Wings')
print(names_to_bands['Paul'])


['Beatles', 'Wings']
```

P/S/ names_to_bands = {'John': ['Beatles'], 'George': ['Beatles'], 'Paul': ['Beatles', 'Wings'], 'Ringo': ['Beatles']}

Comment: Покажите код. И что значит "при повторном прогоне"?

Comment: print('имя со списком группы')
band1_names = ['John', 'George', 'Paul', 'Ringo']
band2_names = ['Paul','DD']
names_to_bands = {}
for name in band1_names:
    names_to_bands.setdefault(name,['Beatles'])
for name in band2_names:
    names_to_bands.setdefault(name,[]).append('Wings')
print(names_to_bands['Paul'])
print(names_to_bands)

Comment: А что не так? Вы же сами `.append()` делаете.

Comment: почему он выполняется? если выполняться должен только если нет имени name

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно используете `setdefault` в комбинации с `append`. Главное, что вызов этого метода и вызов `append` независимы.

`setdefault` возвращает значение из `dict` по ключу (подобно тому, как это делает `get` или `[]`), а в случае, если такого ключа нет, добавляет в `dict` значение для данного ключа, переданное вторым параметром. И самое главное, что `append` вызывается в любом случае для списка.

Это значит, что эта строка:

```
names_to_bands.setdefault(name,[]).append('Wings')
```

работает так:

1. если `name` в `names_to_bands` нет, то она эквивалента `names_to_bands[name] = ['Wings']`
2. если `name` в `names_to_bands` уже есть, то она эквивалентна `names_to_bands[name].append('Wings')`

Т.е. при повторном вызове добавится дубликат, что вы и наблюдаете.

То, что вам нужно делается так:

```
bands = names_to_bands.setdefault(name,[])
if 'Wings' not in bands:
    bands.append('Wings')
```

либо используйте `set` вместо списка:

```
names_to_bands.setdefault(name, set()).add('Wings')
```

Comment: Спасибо.работатет она правильно. (так задано). Просто не понятно почему она не пропускает . ведь по условию она д.была работать: уже есть пошли дальше